# facing an issue with the sort function in cpp

Tags: c++, sorting

trying to sort a dynamic array sum_array but the function is not working.also my loop used to self terminate if i dont put the size of array as 1 could there be something with my declaration

```
**#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){

  vector <int> sum_array (1);
  int n;
  cin>>n;
  int sum,marks;
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    cout<<"turn now is ="<<i<<endl;
    sum=0;
    for (int k = 0; k < (n-1); k++) {
    cin>>marks;
    sum=sum+marks;
    cout<<"sum="<<sum<<endl;
    }
  sum_array[i]=sum;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    cout<<sum_array[i]<<endl;
  }
  sort(sum_array.begin(),sum_array.end());
  cout<<"after"<<endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    cout<<sum_array[i]<<endl;
  }
    return 0;
}**
```

Comment: You create `sum_array` with one element but then set `sum_array[i]` with `i` in the range [0, 5) without ever resizing.  That's undefined behaviour.  It also means `sort` will only consider that one item.

Comment: `sum_array` is given a size of one element, but elements `0` to `4` are assigned.   Assigning elements like that does not implicitly resize.   Instead, your code has undefined behaviour.

Comment: i thought vector was a dynamic array that doubles up on its own.if its showing me elements from 0 to 4 that means they were fitted by resizing the array then why is it undefined when i try to sort them. how do i fix it?

Comment: Do not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`, [see why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a vector of one integer:

```
std::vector<int> sum_array(1);
```

Then you access elements out of bounds of the vector (which is undefined behaviour).

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  // ...
  sum_array[i] = sum;
}
```

`std::sort` is only sorting a vector of one element so it isn't doing anything.

Since you do not know the size of the vector, you should initialize it as an empty vector:

```
std::vector<int> sum_array;
```

and push the elements into the `sum_array`:

```
sum_array.push_back(sum);
```